# Selecting randomly a subset of a large number samples in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a subset of n samples from a large number of N samples, n << N. I usually use randperm function in Matlab and take the first n indices . However, since the data can be very large, randperm give me error message of not enough memory.

I would like to have suggestions, how can I select a small subset out of a large number of data set without using randperm function in Matlab.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `randsample`?

Comment: I don't know about it before, but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `n` is much smaller than `N`, a [rejection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is efficient: generate a sample with possible repetitions using [`randi`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html), check if there are repetitions (which is not very likely), and if so repeat:

```
N = 10000;
n = 100;
repeat = true;
while repeat
    sample = randi(N,1,n);
    repeat = any(sum(bsxfun(@eq, sample, sample.'))>1);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use single() to halve the datasize:

http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/single.html

Answer (score 0):

`randi` gives uniformly distributed numbers,

```
Ind = randi(N,[n 1]);
Observation = data(Ind);
```

You could also use `datasample`,

```
Observation = datasample(data,n,'Replace',false));
```

As @Shai mentioned, another option would be `randsample`,

```
Observation = data(randsample(N,n));
```